# A functional on paths in a symplectic vector space

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, terminology, partitions

I'm running into a functional associated to a piecewise smooth curve $\gamma: [0,1] \to V$, where $V$ is a real vector space with a symplectic form $\omega$:

$$ \int_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1} \omega(\gamma'(x), \gamma'(y))\ dx\ dy $$

> Is this a standard concept? In particular, does it have a name?

In my application, $\gamma$ is something like the path from SW to NE under a partition, and this functional is the area of the partition. (Though generally I'm working in higher dimension.)

Comment: Are you assuming that $\omega$ has constant coefficients (when expressed in linear coordinates on $V$)?  If so, then this integral can be evaluated explicitly as integrating over $\gamma$ the 1-form $\alpha$ defined at each point as $\alpha_v(w) = \omega(v,w)$ and then then subtracting $\omega(\gamma(0),\gamma(1))$.  Otherwise, your functional reminds me of K. T. Chen's iterated integrals.  Maybe looking at those references will turn up the kind of thing you might be looking for.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming constant coefficients; I'd hoped "vector space with a symplectic form" to mean that, as opposed to "symplectic manifold that happens to be diffeomorphic to a vector space". I'll see if I can make use of the 1-form. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry about being nit-picky; I thought that was what you meant, but I wasn't sure.  I guess the phrase "Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic vector space" would have removed all doubt for me about what you meant. (Also, the title of the question should have given me a clue.)  I was also a little imprecise in my answer, since I should have written "integrating $\gamma^*\alpha$ over $[0,1]$, where $\alpha$ is the $1$-form on $V$ defined at each $v\in V$ by $\alpha_v(w) = \omega(v,w)$", etc.  Btw, the only critical points of your functional are the constant maps.